# Unity3d Android Java heap space error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin

I have a unity3d Android project that has 500 mg APK. I have started to get "Java heap size error" and I know how to solve this in Android Studio, just increase the size in gradle.properties file, but on Unity? Unity only let`s you "see" the mainTemplate.gradle file.

I am using Unity3d 2018.1.0f2 editor.

I have also tried to use Internal build system but when I do that my game simply don`t work, but the build passes.

I have exposed the custom gradle file (Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle) and added the field and values in the Android field like this:

```
dexOptions {
    // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"        
}
```

But the error persists. Did anyone had this kind of problems with Unity Android builds ?

[image]

Adding Build-settings screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of the Build Settings Windows?

Comment: Added the image

Comment: Change `javaMaxHeapSize "8g"` to `javaMaxHeapSize "4g"`?

Comment: @Programmer , did that too. That was initially. No luck.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error, because the JVM (in which gradle is executed for example) exceeded the RAM limit.

Since at least Unity 2018.3.x there is a setting for the maximum RAM of the JVM at: Edit->Preferences->External Tools->Maximum JVM Heap Size, Mbytes (default 4096)
Increasing it to 8192 solved the problem for me. (JVM needed 5,5GB RAM)

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Unity: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2017-3-fails-gradle-build-due-to-java-heap-memory.514916/

The following worked for me:

```
Selecting Internal Build instead of Gradle bypassed it for my work.
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yea, internal build passes for me too, but the game doesnt work. It stucks at black screen and that`s it.